# WebSocket with Sockjs & Spring 4 but without Stomp

Tags: java, websocket, sockjs, spring-4

Is there a way to use WebSockets with SockJS client and Spring 4 server but not using STOMP?

Based on this tutorial from Spring's website, I know how to set up a WebSocket based application using Stomp and Spring 4. On the client side, we have:

```
     var socket = new SockJS('/hello');
        stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
        stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
            setConnected(true);
            console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
            stompClient.subscribe('/topic/greetings', function(greeting){
                showGreeting(JSON.parse(greeting.body).content);
            });
        });
```

And on the server side, we have the following in the controller:

```
@MessageMapping("/hello")
@SendTo("/topic/greetings")
public Greeting greeting(HelloMessage message) throws Exception {
    Thread.sleep(3000); // simulated delay
    return new Greeting("Hello, " + message.getName() + "!");
}
```

Now, I understand that `@MessageMapping("/hello")` ensures that if a message is sent to a destination `"/hello"`, then the `greeting()` method will be called. And since the `stompClient` is subscribed to `"/topic/greetings"`, the `@SendTo("/topic/greetings")` will send the message back to the `stompClient`.

But the problem with the above is that stompClient is a Stomp object. And I want to simply use `sock.send('test');` and have it delivered to my server's destination. And I want to do `@SendTo("myownclientdestinationmap")`, I can receive it by

```
sock.onmessage = function(e) {
     console.log('message', e.data);
 };
```

So, any way to do this with Spring 4, SockJS and without Stomp? Or does Spring 4 WebSocket only supports Stomp?

Comment: I want to use WebSocket in my `spring-mvc` application,  could you please guide/tell me why you don't want to use `STOMP` ?, thank you !!!

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Spring supports `STOMP` over `WebSocket` but the use of a subprotocol is **not mandatory**, you can deal with the raw websocket. When using a raw websocket, the message sent lacks of information to make Spring route it to a specific message handler method (we don't have any messaging protocol), so instead of annotating your controller, you'll have to implement a `WebSocketHandler`:

```
public class GreetingHandler extends TextWebSocketHandler {

    @Override
    public void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message) {
        Thread.sleep(3000); // simulated delay
        TextMessage msg = new TextMessage("Hello, " + message.getPayload() + "!");
        session.sendMessage(msg);
    }
}
```

And then add your handler to the registry in the configuration (you can add more than one handler and use `SockJS` for fallback options):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(greetingHandler(), "/greeting").withSockJS();
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSocketHandler greetingHandler() {
        return new GreetingHandler();
    }
}
```

The client side will be something like this:

```
var sock = new SockJS('http://localhost:8080/greeting');

sock.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log('message', e.data);
}
```

Comment: hello @Sergi Almar  ,I have one question here ,using spring 4 is it possible to connect to web socket using `new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/my-app/ws-connect-url');`?

Comment: Sure, just remove the .withSockJS(); from the configuration and use the plain JS WebSocket API (you won't have any fallback options)

Comment: This answer works great, but I now I wonder: is it possible in this setup to broadcast a message to all connected clients? It is straightforward in plain JSR356 websockets, so I hope it is doable here too.

Comment: Created a separate question from my last comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33910639/4358405

Comment: It doesn't work for me using it without .withSockJS() -> can't connect using "ws://localhost....", could you help?
I'm using spring boot

Comment: Websocket client doesn't work with Spring boot 1.3.2 with authentication.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35332080/spring-boot-authentication-with-tyrus-websocket-client-causes-authenticationexce

Comment: @SergiAlmar could u please help me for [How to properly configure Stomp and SockJS endpoint in Spring MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47551224/3425489)