# How to broadcast a message using raw Spring 4 WebSockets without STOMP?

Tags: spring, websocket, spring-4

In this great answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27161986/4358405 there is an example of how to use raw Spring4 WebSockets without STOMP subprotocol (and without SockJS potentially).

Now my question is: how do I broadcast to all clients? I expected to see an API that I could use in similar fashion with that of pure JSR 356 websockets API: `session.getBasicRemote().sendText(messJson);`

Do I need to keep all `WebSocketSession` objects on my own and then call `sendMessage()` on each of them?

Comment: Hi, Have the same question you have: how do I broadcast to all clients? did you have/got the answer for this ? thanks for you help.

Answer (score 6):

I found a solution. In the WebSocket handler, we manage a list of WebSocketSession and add new session on afterConnectionEstablished function.

```
private List<WebSocketSession> sessions = new ArrayList<>();

synchronized void addSession(WebSocketSession sess) {
    this.sessions.add(sess);
}

@Override
public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) throws Exception {
    addSession(session);
    System.out.println("New Session: " + session.getId());
}
```

When we need to broadcast, just enumerate through all session in list **sessions** and send messages.

```
for (WebSocketSession sess : sessions) {
        TextMessage msg = new TextMessage("Hello from " + session.getId() + "!");
        sess.sendMessage(msg);
}
```

Hope this help!

Comment: I'm aware of that solution - this looks exactly like an implementation of the solution I've already mentioned in my question. I rather wanted to know if it has any downsides and there is a better approach or this is actually the best solution.

Comment: So what solution did u come up with @TMG ? Im doing as same solution here, did it work fine for you?

Comment: @SepehrGH At that time I did not find anything better. I have not faced any particular issues with this solution, but don't take it as my endorsement. I have stopped working on that project soon after and I can't really tell if it worked good or not.

Comment: @TMG thanks for the information. I'm using this approach in our messaging system (self-developed protocol)... think it will work fine

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know and can gather from the documentation [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html) you can't broadcast using the `WebSocketHandler`.

Instead you should use `Stomp` over `WebSocket` configured by a `WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer` as described [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-stomp-enable).

Use a `SimpMessagingTemplate` anywhere in your code to send messages to subscribed clients as described [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-stomp-handle-send.)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "you can't do this"? I can't use a broadcast API because it doesn't exist, or I can't keep a `List<WebSocketSession>` because of some other implications that I'm not aware of ?

Comment: i tried SimpMessagingTemplate but it is not able to send, there are no errors, please help