# Spring websockets without STOMP and SockJs but with message broker and routing support

Tags: java, spring, spring-websocket, java-websocket

Is there a way to use the facilities provided by Spring to have a webSocket connection without using SockJS and STOMP? I need to implement a proprietary webSocket protocol so I cannot use either one at the moment.

I have implemented/hacked together the solution from the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27158106/websocket-with-sockjs-spring-4-but-without-stomp), but it requires me to reimplement things that I feel I should not be worrying about.

I guess my question boils down to: is there a way for me to use the nice features of `2.`(below), specifically the MessageBroker,  without using STOMP?

A bit of background:

I need to do the following:

- Be able to inject a reference to my persistence provider in each instance of the websocket handler
- Handle each webSocket session in a separate instance of my handler object
- Re-transmit the messages I receive on one endpoint to multiple clients on a different endpoint.
- Implement my own protocol over a standard Text WebSocket connection.

What I have tried so far is:

1. Use javax.websocket, where I can handle each request on a separate instance. However, I need to iterate over the open sessions and retransmit on the ones connected to the correct endpoint. Also, I can't use Spring to inject my persistence provider. This was what I was using so far and it seems too hacky.

I.e. (pseudo-code)

```
@ServerEndpoint("/trade/{id}")
public String handleMessage(@PathParam(id) String id, webSocketSession session){
 if(id.equalsIgnoreCase("foo"){
      for(Session s: session.getOpenSessions(){
      //do things}
  } else if(id.equalsIgnoreCase("bar")){
      //do other things
  }
 }
}
```

2. Use the Spring websocket implementation with `@MessageMapping("/trade")` and `@SendTo("/queue/position-updates")`. This requires me to use, as a minimum, STOMP. This would mean breaking other applications in the process, which I can't do at the moment. Also, there is the question of the proprietary protocol I need to implement.

I.e. (pseudo-code)

```
@MessageMapping("/trade/{id}")
@SendTo("/trades/all")
public Greeting greeting(String message){
    //do things, return message
}
```

3. A the moment, I am using the Spring websocket implementation by implementing the WebSocketConfigurer class and registering endpoints. This allows me to have each session in a separate handler class and inject the persistence provider. However, I can't seem to get some of the nice things about Spring working:

   - I cannot get the parameter `{id}` from the `registry.addHandler(WebsocketHandlerPool(), "/trade/{id}")` into the `WebsocketHandlerPool()`, so I have to parse the path when I create each individual `WebsocketHandler`. Ideally, I would like to not have to do this.
   - I have to implement my own message broker if I don't want to iterate over all the sessions inside the code of the websocket message handler. There is no support (as far as I can tell) for `@MessageMapping` and `@SendTo`.

I.e. (pseudo-code for handler:)

```
@Override
public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession s){
    //parses the String of the Path URL and sets it as a field
    idFromSessionPath = getIdFromSessionPath(s);
}
@Override
public String handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message
{
    If(idFromSessionPath.equals("foo"){
     //do things
    } else {
     //do other things
    }
}
```

(pseudo-code for config)

```
@Override
public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry  registry){
    registry.addHandler(threadPool(), "/trade/{id}");
}

@Bean
public WebSocketHandler threadPool(){
    return new PerConnectionWebSocketHandler(TradeStreamingHandler.class);

}
```

Comment: I am currently in a very similar situation as you were when you wrote this, and I am sad to see that there has not been a reply. Were you able to come up with a solution or did you have what you showed in your pseudo-code for handler? 

I am definitely interested in how you solved this as I'm currently doing what you're showing in your pseudo-code handler.