# How to subscribe websocket by Chrome extensions?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, sockets, websocket, spring-websocket

I am try to implement a basic web socket app by following this tutorial:https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/

However, in that tutorial there was a client UI implementation. I don't want to use UI. Instead of the UI, I want to use a websocket client extension in Chrome for sending and seeing messages.

All codes same with the tutorial(except the UI part since I'dont want UI), so I don't rewrite all codes here.

I am able to connect and send message to the url: `ws://localhost:8081/gs-guide-websocket` for example,

[image]

However, I can't get response with this url: `ws://localhost:8081/topic/greetings`. (I use this URL for getting responses by subscribing it. Because this `topic/greetings` path used in the UI side of that tutorial for subscription)
[image]

The Chrome extension that I used is Simple WebSocket Client.

Why I couldn't subscribe the `ws://localhost:8081/topic/greetings` url? and How can I get messages from the server by using the Chrome client websocket extensions?

Answer (score 0):

Your application works with **STOMP** and **SockJs**, this plugin does not support that. It only works with ws. In this example, you can write a simple ws endpoint for your application:
[example simple ws endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27158106/websocket-with-sockjs-spring-4-but-without-stomp)